# Java server invalid execption. Socket

Tags: java, image, sockets, chat, server

I have been fixing my server many times and now i'm stuck ones again.

So I have been trying to send pictures through my clientGUI to a server, So the person can see the file im sending. I dont really know how to explain this. but however. Im just trying to send a file so the other client can accept it and save it. BUT as fast as I press the button picture (It should automatic send a picture to a desktop that I have placed) it does work,

> Connection is accepted; localhost/127.0.0.1 - 1500
>   Sending C:/Users/Barry/Desktop/Ceo/Cao6.jpg(15306 bytes)
>   Server has closed the connection

but i'm not getting anything in the desktop and in my ServerGUI, I can see that it says :

```
Exception reading Streams: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: FF
```

which I have no idea how to fix it and I need some ideas how I can fix this.

**Sendpic.java**

```
public void SendPic() throws IOException {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    String FILESEND = "C:/Users/Barry/Desktop/Ceo/Cao6.jpg";
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    OutputStream os = null;

    try {

        // send file

        File myFile = new File (FILESEND);
        byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
        fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("Sending " + FILESEND + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
        os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**getPic.Java**

```
     final static int FILE_SIZE = 6022386;
public void getPic() throws IOException {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    String FILETORECEIVED = "C:/Users/Barry/Desktop/";

     int bytesRead;
     int current = 0;

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try {

    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [FILE_SIZE];
      InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
      fos = new FileOutputStream(FILETORECEIVED);
      bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
      bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      current = bytesRead;

      do {
         bytesRead =
            is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
         if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
      } while(bytesRead > -1);

      bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
      bos.flush();
      System.out.println("File " + FILE_SIZE
          + " downloaded (" + current + " bytes read)");
}

    finally {
      if (fos != null) fos.close();
      if (bos != null) bos.close();

    }
  }
```

**ActionPerformed**`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object button = e.getSource();


        if (button == btnPicture) {
            try {
                controller.SendPic();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;
        }`
```

Comment: Not clear who is supposed to get the picture -- your both code snippets are trying to write to a socket.

Comment: Oh my bad! Its updated now!

Comment: Anyone that can give me any ideas?